# how to import forex data and read it using yfinance and pandas data reader?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, yahoo-finance, algorithmic-trading

> hello guys, hope you're doing well.
> i used a code that plots renko and counts the bars by importing the data of stocks from yahoo finance and it worked great, but i want to use forex data from yahoo finance in the code but it is not working.

```
Stocklist=['AAPL']
start='2016-1-1'
for stock in StockList:
data[stock]=pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start)
```

> that's how i get stocks data and use it, but its not working for forex, for example EURUSD=X

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
start_date = dt.datetime.today()- dt.timedelta(4000) 
end_date = dt.datetime.today()
stock ="USDJPY=X"
data = yf.download(stock, start_date, end_date)
```

it worked in this way guys